# How many times does a certain sound appear in an audio clip?

Tags: audio, decomposition

I have an audio clip which can be found [here](https://app.box.com/s/lc2jtm8dlyl5koko559nprmmz1hazpxy)  or [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/fbfqiembo3t7o7b/20160907+110003.wav). If you hear the audio clip you will notice that there are six times a kind of hit sound in the clip.

My questions are:

1. How can I count these hit sounds (I should get six in this clip)?
2. What is the best tool/software/app for this problem?
3. Where can I find a good source that explains the theory behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I count these hit sounds ( I should get six in this clip).

In this case you can simply rectify the signal (i.e. run it through an `abs`olute function, then through a simple running average low pass filter and at the output of this add a threshold. Essentially, when the power of the input signal exceeds the threshold you will be receiving a pulse whose width is approximately equal to the duration of the "hit". Alternatively, you can do away with rectification and filtering and simply pass the whole thing via a threshold operator. That is, when the power of the input signal exceeds the threshold, you get a "pulse". In either way, count the "pulses" and you can count the number of "hits" that you have in that wave file.

> What is the best tool/software/app for this problem.

This is not an incredibly challenging Digital Signal Processing task, so you could simply write a Python script that does it in 3-5 lines of code (I am not implying that Python is not capable of serious processing here). Alternatively, you could install something like [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) and again do it in 3-5 lines of code, using [one of its toolboxes](https://www.scilab.org/scilab/features/scilab/signal_processing) (or, [this one](http://atoms.scilab.org/categories/signal_processing)).

> Where can I find a good source that explains the theory behind this.

This "rectify and threshold" technique is a sort of a "standard" in counting pulses, alternatively, you might want to have a look at the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) filter as an example of a sliding window technique where you process a long signal in small "frames" of samples. Other than this, this website has [an extensive list of book references](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=books) if you search for "books".

Hope this helps.